# Proving commutator [${L}_i, f(r)]=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

I am trying to prove that the angular momentum component operator  ${L}_i$ commutes with any function of ${r}\equiv \sqrt{{\textbf{x}}\cdot{\textbf{x}}}$, i.e.

$$[L_i,  f( r)]=0.$$

I first worked out  that $L_i$ commutes with $\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{x}$, i.e. $$[L_i,\textbf{x}^2]=0.$$
I then expanded $f(r)$ in terms of a power series:
$$f(r)=\sum_n a_nr^n=\sum_na_n(\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{x})^{n\over 2}.$$

Next, I want to show that $L_i$ commutes with $(\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{x})^{n\over 2}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, i.e.
$$[L_i,(\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{x})^{n\over 2}]=0.$$

What commutator rule can I use to evaluate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of proving this, as other answers show. Here is another one. There is a general identity that states that if $[x, y]=0$, then $[x,f(y)]=0$, where $f$ is some function. The result you are after follows immediately from this, with $f(y)=\sqrt y$.

To prove this identity, let us first show that $[x,y]=0$ implies $[x, y^n]$, where $n$ is any non-negative integer. We can do this by induction. Suppose that $[x,y^m]=0$ for all $m<n$. Then,
$$\begin{aligned} \left[x, y^n\right] & = xy^n-y^nx \\ &= xy^{n-1}y -y^{n-1}yx \\ &= y^{n-1}xy-y^{n-1}yx\\ &=y^{n-1}[x,y] \\ &= 0. \end{aligned}$$
Then, since $f(y)$ can be expanded into a Taylor series involving powers of $y$, it follows from $[x,y]=0$ that $[x,f(y)]=0$.

**Edit:** As has been brought up in comments, the square root function is not actually analytic on $\mathbb{C}$, although it can be chosen to be analytic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. This would mean the proof may not be valid for this function. I'm not exactly sure that the function being non-analytic at $0$ invalidates this approach though, so I will keep this answer so others can comment on this, and also because $[x,f(y)]=0$ (with $f$ analytic) is a useful identity.

Comment: Wow, this is such a nice proof. Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: But $f(y)=\sqrt{y}$ is not analytic (not even differentiable), what am I missing?

Comment: @user2723984 Thanks for catching this, this may indeed invalidate the proof in the answer. I have edited my answer to caution the readers.

Answer (score 5):

The answers given by Philip and Alexander are correct, but let me add another snippet of information: one could calculate the commutation in the polar coordinates! Then:
$$\hat{L}_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i},$$
whereas $f(r)$ is obviously independent on angle $\phi_i$.

Comment: Oooh! This is **such** a satisfying explanation. I've never thought about it before.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

There is a basic identity (derived upon several restrictions) that in your case reads as -
$$[L_i,f(r)]=[L_i,r]f'(r)$$
Applying the same relation you can show that if operator commutes with $r$, it commutes with any function of $r$
You can also use the following for $L_i$ to relax the expression -
$$[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$$

@Philips answer also useful, though in general case (when the operator doesn't commute with the commutator) the order (which side to land the $f'$) matters. In this case you should be able to use the identities to break the expression up to $[x,p]$ commutator, which is constant, thus commutes with everything.

Hint 2:

The following reference seems very helpful for the most general case

http://hdl.lib.byu.edu/1877/1263

General answer:

Essentially, angular momentum operators operate on angle variables (real space representation), while the $f(r)$ function is independent of angular coordinates. Thus you can switch freely the order of operators.

The following reference has solution to your question

http://www.physics.ucc.ie/apeer/PY3102/Angular_momentum.pdf

Comment: Do you mind linking me to a proof on the identity $[L_i,f(r)]=[L_i,r]f'(r)$? I tried searching on google but can't find it. The link in Hint 2 described the identity and linked me to a textbook which left the proof as an exercise.Thank you!

Comment: The proof is very similar to your original direction (you were on the right track to prove the general identity necessary to solve the question). You expand $r$ in power series, and repeatedly use the commutation relation identity I wrote, leaving only $r$ (r to power of 1) within the commutator. Then you collect the terms "left out" outside the commutator (this is why the order where to put $f'(r)$ matters, to the left or to the right of the commutator, as it's not necesarily commutes with the operator on the other side) and recognize that it is the power series of $f'(r)$

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following rule that states that if you have two operators $A$ and $B$ such that $[B,[A,B]]=0$, then

$$[A, f(B)] = f'(B)[A,B].$$

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same question in 2023. Though using spherical coordinates (as pointed out by @Roger Vadim) is for sure one way to prove $[L_i, f(r)]=0$, if one is sticking to the Cartesian ones, one may try, for example:

$$
\begin{split}
[L_z, f(r)]g(r)
&=L_zf(r)g(r)-f(r)L_zg(r)\\
&=(xp_y-yp_x)f(r)g(r)-f(r)(xp_y-yp_x)g(r)\\
&=(-i\hbar x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+i\hbar y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})[f(r)g(r)]-f(r)(-i\hbar x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+i\hbar y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})g(r)\\
&=i\hbar [-xg(r)\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial y}+yg(r)\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial x}]\\
&=i\hbar[-xg(r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+yg(r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}]\\
&=i\hbar[-xg(r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{y}{r}+yg(r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{x}{r}]\\
&=0
\end{split}$$

where g(r) is just a test function and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{r}$ and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{r}$. Thus, $[L_z,f(r)]=0$. The same goes for $[L_x,f(r)]$ and $[L_y,f(r)]$.